# Frustrated with GPG signing aptly administered repository

Tags: linux, debian, gnupg, apt-get

We host some of our own software packages as debs in a repository of our own. For prototyping purposes, we’ve been running “unauthenticated”. Now we're trying to do things more correctly and do the whole GPG thing. What I’ve tried, just for test run is the following:

1) Make a key with `gpg-gen`

```
~$ gpg --list-keys
/home/me/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
pub   4096R/BBBBB39F 2017-03-09
uid                  Someone Somebody <someone@somewhere.com>
sub   4096R/129E9336 2017-03-09
```

(what btw, is the SUB thing there?)

2) `aptly publish`... This prompts me for my passphrase for said key, so it must be doing something with the key at that point.

3) export the key using `gpg —export —armor > somefile.pubkey`

4) copy some file.pubkey over to a test machine

5) run `sudo apt-key add somefile.pubkey`

```
sudo apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-03-09 [SC]
     E51B E216 4658 FB8B 6E42  8A09 F9BC EF4C BBBB B39F
uid           [ unknown] Someone Somebody <someone@somewhere.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-03-09 [E]
…
…
…
```

So, it seems to have gotten in there. The sub thing shows up differently now?

6) And finally, `sudo apt-get update`:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease     
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease          
Get:4 http://our.aptly.repo stretch InRelease [2317 B]
Ign:4 http://our.aptly.repo stretch InRelease            
Fetched 2317 B in 9s (256 B/s)                                                 
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://our.aptly.repo stretch InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: E51BE2164658FB8B6E428A09F9BCEF4CBBBBB39F
W: The repository 'http://our.aptly.repo stretch InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don’t understand what’s happening here. The offense seems to be that something is not signed? What step did I miss?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `aptly publish` isn't doing all it should be to sign the repository files and set everything up correctly, maybe it's got a verbose flag? Maybe someone or an answer on serverfault has more info, seems generally about setting up a repository server...?

Comment: I don't know. I'm running aptly version 0.9.6 on Ubuntu 16. It's pretty up to date, and aptly's now been around for a while, and their tutorials jump into GPG signing right away. It seems if this was borked, it would have been an issue a long time ago. I don't have any evidence either way, but it seems unlikely that this would be broken still if it was.

Comment: Anyway, I *did* follow the implied advice to post the same/similiar question over on ServerFault. We'll see if that bears any more fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in the comments that you're using Aptly v0.9.6. Aptly used SHA1 signatures until 0.9.7 ([relevant PR](https://github.com/smira/aptly/pull/366), note that it was also backported to v0.9.6.1), which an up-to-date Debian stretch install will no longer accept. Consider adding [their repo](https://www.aptly.info/download/) to your sources.list so you can use a newer version.